# How to connect to a JDA server from Python

Tags: java, python

I am having a JDA server with connection details . I have to connect to this JDA server from my python program and execute MOCA commands. I have searched and haven't found any documentation on the same so far.

Found some jar files and all but nothing with python.My python client app has to connect to JDA and execute commands.

executed requests and got the session-key values. also executed the commands with session-key but output is not getting reflected.

Called this particular command to login with request body as.

```
<moca-request autocommit="True">
  <environment>
    <var name="USR_ID" value="super"/>
  </environment>
  <query>login user where usr_id = 'super' and usr_pswd = 'super'</query>
</moca-request>
```

I am able to login successfully and got the response as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<moca-response>
    <session-id></session-id>
    <status>0</status>
    <moca-results>
        <metadata>
            <column name="usr_id" type="S" length="0" nullable="true"/>
            <column name="locale_id" type="S" length="0" nullable="true"/>
            <column name="addon_id" type="S" length="0" nullable="true"/>
            <column name="cust_lvl" type="I" length="0" nullable="true"/>
            <column name="session_key" type="S" length="0" nullable="true"/>
            <column name="pswd_expir" type="I" length="0" nullable="true"/>
            <column name="pswd_expir_dte" type="D" length="0" nullable="true"/>
            <column name="pswd_disable" type="I" length="0" nullable="true"/>
            <column name="pswd_chg_flg" type="O" length="0" nullable="true"/>
            <column name="pswd_expir_flg" type="O" length="0" nullable="true"/>
            <column name="pswd_warn_flg" type="O" length="0" nullable="true"/>
            <column name="srv_typ" type="S" length="0" nullable="true"/>
            <column name="super_usr_flg" type="O" length="0" nullable="true"/>
            <column name="ext_ath_flg" type="O" length="0" nullable="true"/>
        </metadata>
        <data>
            <row>
                <field>SUPER</field>
                <field>US_ENGLISH</field>
                <field>3pl,WM,SEAMLES,3pl</field>
                <field>10</field>
                <field>;uid=SUPER|sid=b6698786-85dc-41ec-9e54-c0d8f99b5cbf|dt=jttyorn7|sec=ALL;Hz1biv4HuD_Uq3g.R9QtCfwjQ0</field>
                <field null="true"></field>
                <field null="true"></field>
                <field>6008</field>
                <field>0</field>
                <field>0</field>
                <field>0</field>
                <field>DEVELOPMENT</field>
                <field>1</field>
                <field>0</field>
            </row>
        </data>
    </moca-results>
</moca-response>
```

I have taken the session key as**;uid=SUPER|sid=b6698786-85dc-41ec-9e54-c0d8f99b5cbf|dt=jttyorn7|sec=ALL;Hz1biv4HuD_Uq3g.R9QtCfwjQ0** as per the xml response and tried executing the commands.

This is how i executed the commands

```
<moca-request autocommit="True">
  <environment>
    <var name="USR_ID" value="super"/>
    <var name="SESSION_KEY" value=";uid=SUPER|sid=b6698786-85dc-41ec-9e54-c0d8f99b5cbf|dt=jttyorn7|sec=ALL;Hz1biv4HuD_Uq3g.R9QtCfwjQ0"/>
    <var name="LOCALE_ID" value="US_ENGLISH"/>
    <var name="MOCA_APPL_ID" value="MYAPP"/>
  </environment>
 <query>
     create record where table = 'alt_prtmst' and prtnum = 'TEST1' and alt_prtnum = 'TEST123' and alt_prt_typ = 'SAP' and prt_client_id = '----' </query>
</moca-request>
```

the commands execute without any error and i am getting response also as.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<moca-response>
    <session-id></session-id>
    <status>0</status>
</moca-response>
```

but changes are not getting reflected.

I also tried another moca command in query..

```
<query>
    list warehouses
</query>
```

Even if it executes how to get the exact output back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have interpreted your question that you are trying to connect to a JDA (WMS) instance.
I have created an application in NodeJs that connects to an instance and executes MOCA commands.

I am posting XML with the request header `'Content-Type': 'application/moca-xml'` to `<host>:<port>/service`. The example XML body below will run the `list user tables` MOCA command.

```
<moca-request autocommit="True">
  <environment>
    <var name="USR_ID" value="..."/>
    <var name="SESSION_KEY" value="..."/>
    <var name="LOCALE_ID" value="EN-GB"/>
    <var name="MOCA_APPL_ID" value="MYAPP"/>
  </environment>
  <query>list user tables</query>
</moca-request>
```

The `SESSION_KEY` can be taken from the repsponse of a login request, XML body below.

```
<moca-request autocommit="True">
  <environment>
    <var name="USR_ID" value="..."/>
  </environment>
  <query>login user where usr_id = '...' and usr_pswd = '...'</query>
</moca-request>
```

Comment: can you please explain.. is it a post request we have to make? Also where are you specigying the 'list user tables ' moca command . @wbarton

Comment: Yes it is a post request. The 'list user tables' command is available on the MOCA server, any command can be passed to the server by adding it to  the `<query>` in the XML.

Comment: so the rest endpoint will be host:port/service   What is service here? is it a hard coded static value

Comment: Yes, _service_ is a static value.

Comment: Thanks this is working.. but not able to find the session key

Comment: The session key is returned as part of the response from a login request, I have updated the answer with the required XML body.

Comment: thanks i have tried using your updated answer and am getting session-id as well. but however when i execute the command,it is not reflecting at all. always getting same response. I have updated my question with details..

Comment: Inside the `moca-response` will be a `moca-results` element, that contains any returned data.

Comment: why am i not getting any moca-results in the response.. is there anything i am doing wrong @wbarton?

Comment: Lets take this discussion to a chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191027/jda-conversation

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py) to connect to a discord server from python. An example follows:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

description = '''An example bot to showcase the discord.ext.commands extension
module.

There are a number of utility commands being showcased here.'''
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', description=description)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')

@bot.command()
async def add(left : int, right : int):
    """Adds two numbers together."""
    await bot.say(left + right)

@bot.command()
async def roll(dice : str):
    """Rolls a dice in NdN format."""
    try:
        rolls, limit = map(int, dice.split('d'))
    except Exception:
        await bot.say('Format has to be in NdN!')
        return

    result = ', '.join(str(random.randint(1, limit)) for r in range(rolls))
    await bot.say(result)

@bot.command(description='For when you wanna settle the score some other way')
async def choose(*choices : str):
    """Chooses between multiple choices."""
    await bot.say(random.choice(choices))

@bot.command()
async def repeat(times : int, content='repeating...'):
    """Repeats a message multiple times."""
    for i in range(times):
        await bot.say(content)

@bot.command()
async def joined(member : discord.Member):
    """Says when a member joined."""
    await bot.say('{0.name} joined in {0.joined_at}'.format(member))

@bot.group(pass_context=True)
async def cool(ctx):
    """Says if a user is cool.

    In reality this just checks if a subcommand is being invoked.
    """
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
        await bot.say('No, {0.subcommand_passed} is not cool'.format(ctx))

@cool.command(name='bot')
async def _bot():
    """Is the bot cool?"""
    await bot.say('Yes, the bot is cool.')

bot.run('token')
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: the way i read it, OP has a bot running JDA (a wrapper for the discord api), and wants to remote-control the bot from his python script - not run the bot itself in python.